# Is there a Ubuntu Server Minimal CD?

Tags: release-management

Is there a Ubuntu Server Minimal CD? This can be helpful when you want to install Ubuntu on a server through KVM by selecting a local ISO file and the upload speed on your local computer is not great.

Comment: Minimal + server would defy the purpose of minimal. "server minimal" = "server".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this wiki page which contains a list of Ubuntu minimal CDs:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD